# How do I handle MavenCentral being blocked when it comes to React Native dependencies installed via NPM?

Tags: android, react-native, maven, gradle, nexus

I'm fairly new to android dependency management.

My company is planning to block access to MavenCentral and proxy packages through our internal Sonatype Nexus Registry. We can achieve this by adding our registry's url in `build.gradle`'s `repositories {}` block and removing `MavenCentral()`, but what can I do about `build.gradle` files in packages brought in via NPM?

As an example, here is react-native-svg's `android/build.gradle` file: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg/blob/main/android/build.gradle#L76

I know with NPM this is generally handled with a `.npmrc` file, but gradle doesn't seem to have a similar configuration option.

I also know it's fairly standard to not allow access to public registries with production builds, so this must be a solved problem and there's something I don't understand.

- I've tried searching around for a way to override the result of `mavenCentral()` in all build.gradle files globally
- I've tried seeing if the [React Native Gradle Plugin](https://reactnative.dev/docs/react-native-gradle-plugin)
- I've considered a gradle init script or plugin that goes and replaces one url with another, but asking here before doing such a thing seems like a good idea.